# Special characters don't appear in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, special-characters

I'm trying to display Cyrillic characters but I only get squares and other special characters. I enter them using `Alt + keycode` but it won't work. I tried going to `Insert -> Symbols` and they are there with exact keycodes. What do I do?

Comment: Try changing the font to a font that supports your characters. I guess `Arial` would do the trick.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work(sorry for answering late)